# explain why re.compile("([abc])+").search('abc').groups() --------> ('c',)

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I don't understanding why I get this result,

```
>>> import re
>>> re.compile("([abc])+").search('abc').groups()
('c',)
>>>
```

anyone can give a step by step explanation like [this](https://docs.python.org/3.5/howto/regex.html#repeating-things) for the working mechanism of this regex?

Comment: Groups capture their last match. `([abc])` would capture `a`, `([abc]){2}` would capture `b`, and `([abc]+)` would capture `abc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`([abc])+` is a greedy regex. That is the `+` after the group would repeat the whole capturing group one or more times which results in capturing only the last matched character. You may consider this `(a)+` simple example. This regex would match all the `a`'s and capture only the last `a` if there are more than one `a`'s placed continuously. If the input contain exactly a single `a`, that `a` would be captured and also if the `a`'s are not placed continuously then each `a`'s must be captured.

If you use this `([abc]+)`, `+` would repeat only the character class one or more times . So this would capture the whole `abc`. A simple example for this case is `(a+)`.

Finally `re.search(regex, string).groups()` would return all the captured characters.